# Why didn't the Ministry of Magic use their apparition tracking more efficiently?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic, apparition

J.K. Rowling said that the Ministry of Magic had their way of tracking apparition back in a 2000 interview.

> Question: How does the wizarding world protect Muggle banks and vaults, etc. from wizards apparating into them and stealing the contents?
> J.K. Rowling responds: Well, the **Ministry of Magic keeps tabs on people apparating**. That's why you have to have a license to do it, and the **moment you abuse it you can find yourself in serious trouble (or Azkaban!)**.

So how come the Ministry of Magic aurors and hit wizards do not know that the Death Eater apparition activity had increased after Voldemort's return in Little Hangleton June 1995?

Comment: Its a bureaucracy.  They don't tend to do things more efficiently.

Comment: @JK. Do you imply that the ministry cares more for muggle banks than for magical lives threatened by Death Eaters?

Comment: @RalfFriedl if it means maintaining the status quo of "Muggles by and large don't know about the wizarding world" by reducing the number of "unexplainable crimes", then yeah, that concern might take a higher priority for the ministry.

Comment: May be its like government trying to decode encrypted data transferred through internet, technically possible but practically unfeasible, and not worth bothering unless you're a high vale target

Comment: But more possibly its just because wizards are not known for their logicals skills.May be they didnt even put together that they should track DE members through their apparition logs

Comment: It is surprising that Voldemort couldn't trace Harry apparating when he took over tbe ministry then.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Bloated bureaucratic organizations tend to care very little for the lives of actual people, regardless of who those are. That's both a literary trope and an actual fact of life. It would be weirder if the Ministry of Magic were written otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

1. First of all, just apperating here and there isn't a crime. Most death eaters are normal and even respected members of society. So there would be nothing to report for the surveilance team.
2. Maybe there are even death eaters in this department, hiding their operations. Switching out IDs, so a Bellatrix apparating would instead register as Jane Doe apparating, while the real Jane Doe was made to "never apparate again".
3. The amount of apparations being done probably forces the department to focus on specific locations.

> At the beginning of book 7 this is even directly mentioned. The death eaters in the ministery have set up apparation surveillance for the house of the dursleys and the immediate proximity. That is the reason they have to leave by broom.

Answer (score 0):

The ministry of magic don´t recognize the return of Voldemort in 1995 so they also don´t recognize any activity of Death Eaters because the only Death Eater they recognize outside of Azkaban is Sirius Black and he is inside a house.

The ministry could see Lucius Malfoy notable citizen apparating with his old friends also notable citizen but that is not gonna cause any doubts or these doubts could be dissipated with money.